# Laravel, using date differences with multiple variables

Tags: php, laravel

I know that I can use `$date_diff($request->start_date, $request->end_date)` to get the difference between two dates, but I need an explicit date comparison to say "If End date is 60 days greater than start date, print 'error'"

So `$request->end_date > $request->start_date` works in general, but I can't figure out the best way to check if it's 60 days or more than the start date.

What's the best way to do this?

```
$request->start_date->format('Y-m-d');
$request->end_date->format('Y-m-d');

if($request->end_date > $request->start_date) { 
 echo 'Error';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this in many ways.

One solution is to make use of the `diffInDays()` method of Carbon.

```
if ($startDate->diffInDays($endDate) > 60)
{
  // throw an error..
}
```

Or you could add days to the start date, to then compare if this is before or after the second date:

```
if ($startDate->addDays(60)->isBefore($endDate))
{
  // throw an error..
}
```

For more info, check [this section](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) of the Carbon docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel, you have access to the excellent `Carbon` date library.

There are a number of functions for date comparisons but the one you will want is `gt()` (i.e greater than)

```
if ($request->end_date->gt($request->start_date)) { 
    echo 'Error';
}
```

If you want to include equated dates then you can also use `gte()`

---

If `$request->end_date` is not already cast as a `Carbon` object, you can use `Carbon::parse()` or `Carbon::createFromFormat()` to do so.

Documentation can be found [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime` which convert date string to unix timestamp

```
if(strtotime($request->end_date) > ((60*24*60*60) + strtotime($request->start_date))) { 
 echo 'Error';
}
```

Explanation :

`60*24*60*60` is 60 days times 24 hours times 60 minutes time 60 seconds